# How to use rerunFailingTestsCount on Maven install

Tags: maven, selenium, cucumber-jvm, maven-surefire-plugin

I am running my cucumber Scenarios using tymers parallel execution plugin. for that I need use Maven installn to create test runners and to run those runners. I used rerunFailingTest count in maven surefire 2.19.1 and Junit 4.12. but it is not working while nusing maven Install. If I use maven test test ru nners are not generations and my execution is not processing.
can any one please helpi me to resolve this issue to use rerunFailingTestsCount in mven install